# Calculate the difference in 2 years

Tags: r

One year is the birth year, the other is the season year; goal is to calculate the age (in years) during a particular season.  I want to take this info and create a new field (`master$playerAge`) in a merged data set.  I am getting an unfamiliar error and not sure what is causing.  I have confirmed that both `merged.all$yearID` and `merged.all$birthYear` do exist in `merged.all`.  Any help is appreciated.

Code snippet:

```
## calculate age from birthYear and YearId
master$playerAge <- paste(merged.all$yearId - merged.all$birthYear)

Error:
Error in `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) : 
  RHS of assignment to new column 'playerAge' is zero length 
  but not empty list(). For new columns the RHS must either be 
  empty list() to create an empty list column, or, have length > 0; 
  e.g. NA_integer_, 0L, etc.
```

dput() :

Names = c("playerID", "yearID", "teamID", "lgID", "stint", "G", "AB", "R", "SO", "IBB", "HBP", "SH", "SF", "GIDP", "salary", "birthYear", "birthMonth", "birthDay", "birthCountry", "birthState", "birthCity", "deathYear", "deathMonth", "deathDay", "deathCountry", "deathState", "deathCity", "nameFirst", "nameLast", "nameGiven", "weight", "height", "bats", "throws", "debut", "finalGame", "retroID", "bbrefID", "name", "dob"), sorted = "playerID", class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = ) > –

Comment: I don't know why you're using the paste() function.  If 'yearID' and 'birthYear' are  of type POSIXct then you can just subtract them, no need for paste().

Comment: @ Michael - thanks for the tip.  I have removed.

Comment: And you should edit  your `dput` into your question, it's terrible as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i see the typo in your code (small and big "D" letter in "ID"):

I have confirmed that both

```
merged.all$yearID and merged.all$birthYear 

master$playerAge <- paste(merged.all$yearId - merged.all$birthYear)
```